# Saving Entity with a Map

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is there any way I could persist an entity and It's map at the same time?

This example, for instance

```
public class Test {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO) Long id;
    private String name;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Long.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "test1_id")
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "test_id")
    @Column(name = "test")
    private Map<Long, Long> map = new HashMap<>();
}
```

So when I do `test.getMap().put(1L, 2L)` then `testRepository.save(test)` it saves the entity as well as the map?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to make a foreign key constraint or? Yes there is a way, just can you explain what you want to achieve

Comment: I want to save the key and the value in the ``test1_id`` table when I save the ``test`` entity

Comment: you can not save `Map` implementations directly to the database, you can create 2 difference columns 1 for the `Map` key and one for the `Map` value

Comment: Your JPA provider would be able to save a Map in a separate table, yes ... with 3 columns (FK back to owner, key, value). And the problem is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should refactor your entity. I would transform the map in another entity, with two fields of type long. After that, I would link the two entities with a @OneToMany relationship.